# GWT and web template with javascript

Tags: gwt

I have GWT Web application and web template that consists of html+css+javascript files.
UiBinder holds html template in HTMLPanel. Problem is that this template is based on many javascript files and I know that GWT have problems with that. So my page is rendered without some javascript features. 
What can I do with this? What is correct solution for GWT and external web templates?

Comment: What do you mean by "external web templates"?

Comment: I mean simple, common web template that I can buy on templates services.

Comment: Looks like templates for the general layout of your app then. Are you forced to use them in UiBinder? Can't you simply use them as your HTML host page and plug your GWT app **into** it rather than _around_ it?

Comment: I am using UiBinder because before I have worked with gwt widgets only, and now I want to switch to layout template. So sounds like it is good advise. I check this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not GWT-specific: you cannot inject `<script>`s using `innerHTML` (which `HTMLPanel` ultimately uses).

If you need to dynamically inject scripts in your app, then use `ScriptInjector`.

Comment: Yes. I tried ScriptInjector. It seems that problem is that template without gwt execute script after some page is loaded, but template with gwt execute it before rendering page.

Comment: I search for some quick solution because there is a lot of js on that template and if I am right I need to figure out on each script when to inject and execute it.